# refreshing access token and handling infinite http streams

Tags: python, python-requests, refresh-token, http-streaming

I am subscribing to an infinite http stream (current temperature for example), However I need to refresh my access token once every X seconds, how would handle it?

example:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(f'{stream_url}?access_token={access_token}', stream=True)
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):  # this runs forever 
    pass
```

how do i stop the stream and refresh the accesses toke in a non disruptive way?
Is there a library that helps to deal with such a pattern? I am guessing this is pretty common

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to handle token refresh.

1. Store the `token_expires` timestamp with the token and check to make sure it is still valid before each request e.g. (`Time.now() < token_expires`)
2. You could refresh the token whenever you get a 401 respond code from the server

Comment: regrading the first suggestion, when do i check? the `iter_content` is locking my currnet thread, should i have a dedicated thread to token refresh?

Comment: Each iteration of the loop?

Comment: wouldnt this interrupt the stream ?